# Pointer of Pointer of Object dereference?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

**I am a student of computer science. Please read my question completely before posing an answer!**

Good morning Stack Overflow! Today I have a question about dereferencing a pointer of type pointer of type object when passed to a function.

I have an array of Book pointers and an array of pointers of book pointers:

```
Book* pBookArray[5];
Book** sortedPointerArray[5]; // Where sortedPointerArray[k] = &pBookArray[k]
```

I have a function with the prototype and invocation:

```
void sortBooksPointer(Book** sortArray[], int size, int mode)
sortBooksPointer(sortedPointerArray, 5, 0);
```

In this function I am performing a bubble sort on either the title of a book or its author. The sort algorithm works properly and is not the subject of this question. When first writing the function, I tried to do something like the below and had no success:

```
 string tempTitleA = **sortArray[k]->getTitle(); //Or Author depending on mode
```

In the Book class, I have defined a friend to ostream which allows for direct output using `cout`. I decided to do some testing to see if maybe the double-dereference was not properly snagging a book object with the following lines of code:

```
 if (verbose)
{
    cout << "Address of sortedBooks[0]: " << sortArray[0] << endl; // Address of pointer to book pointer
    cout << "Dereference of sortedBooks[0]: " << *sortArray[0] << endl; // Address of the book pointer pointed to by sortedBooks[0]
    cout << "Double deference of sortedBooks[0]:\n" << **sortArray[0] << endl; // Book pointed to by the pointer which sortedBooks[0] points to
}
```

Which performed successfully.

I spent a full day trying to figure out why I could output using the overloaded `operator<<` but could not assign `tempTitleA = **sortArray[k]->getTitle();` before finally giving up and coming up with a hack. Instead of trying to access the getTitle() function of `**sortArray[k]` I am now doing this:

```
Book tempBookA == **sortArray[k];
tempTitleA = tempBookA.getTitle();
```

Which works 100% correctly.

*The question is thus:*
**Why is the double dereference correctly assigning a book to tempBookA, but not allowing direct access to the public functions of that book?**

Thank you in advance for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem of operator precedence. You can do `tempTitleA = (**sortArray[k]).getTitle();`

Comment: I tried this in my code and I receive the following error:
``Book does not have an overloaded operator ->`` and ``left operand had class type``. So I have replaced it with ``tempTitleA = (**sortArray[k].getTitle();`` and this produces the correct response. Why is that the case?

Would this be different than something like... ``(*sortArray[k]->getTitle();``?

Comment: You're right, the first * got a pointer-to-Book (from a pointer-to-pointer) and the second got the Book instance. But you could also have done (*sortArray[k])->getTitle(); Without the parenthesis, the -> or . operator has more precedence than the * operator, thus being equivalent of doing *(sortArray[k]->getTitle()) which would produce an error similar to the first you encountered.